# Http response code for a mixed type of response payload containing both error and success messages

Tags: rest, api, http, http-response-codes

I am developing an API which accepts requests for multiple image uploads in the following format:

```
    {
      "images"[
        {"url": 'www.xyz/image1.jpg', 'type': 'abc'}, 
        {"url": 'www.xyz/image2.jpg', 'type': 'def'}
      ]
    }
```

The response contains success and failure messages for each image:

```
    {
      "error": {
        abc": "Error while downloading image: servname or nodename not known"
      },
      "success": {
        "def": "image got uploaded successfully"
      }
    }
```

Now I am wondering what status code should I return for this response given the possibility that the response can contain only success, only errors or a mix of success and error messages. Should there be a generic status code for this or depending whether the response contains only errors, success or both, the status codes should be different?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `[207 Multi-Status Response][1]`, defined in the [WebDAV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918).

> A Multi-Status response conveys information about multiple resources
> in situations where multiple status codes might be appropriate.  The
> default Multi-Status response body is a text/xml or application/xml
> HTTP entity with a 'multistatus' root element.  Further elements
> contain 200, 300, 400, and 500 series status codes generated during
> the method invocation. 100 series status codes SHOULD NOT be recorded
> in a 'response' XML element.

Comment: While WebDAV is an extension of HTTP, clients might not understand what `207`means. In terms of interoperability of HTTP clients I'd stick to HTTP only. One might argue that `PATCH` is also an extension to HTTP, though here the client targets the server with the request and will receive an appropriate error message according to the HTTP specification if the server does not support `PATCH`. In this scenario, however, the client already used the HTTP protocol to send the request. Returning therefore a status code that is outside of HTTP might break interoperability

Comment: @RomanVottner WebDAV *is* HTTP. `207` is in the IANA registry.: https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml. I don't disagree it might not be correctly implemented on intermediate servers, but it's simply wrong to say it's not part of HTTP.

Comment: I only knew that WebDAV builds on top of HTTP but I wasn't aware that according to IANA it is HTTP actually. To me it always looked like an extension of HTTP and was a separate protocol though. Will have to read up on it actually. I'm still not sure whether most of the clients actually allow WebDAV specific requests like `COPY` or `LOCK` though

Comment: Support is spotty, at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a HTTP response 200 and have the response body contain the further details.
Also you should have a way of mapping the requests to the responses so that you know which success/error message is corresponding to which request.
You can send the request as:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {"key": "1", "url": 'www.xyz/image1.jpg', 'type': 'abc'}, 
    {"key": "2", "url": 'www.xyz/image2.jpg', 'type': 'def'},
    {"key": "3", "url": 'www.xyz/image3.jpg', 'type': 'abc'}
  ]
}
```

And the response as 200 OK with response body:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {"key": "1", "status": "success", "message": "OK"}, 
    {"key": "2", "status": "failure", "message": "some specific error"},
    {"key": "3", "status": "failure", "message": "some specific error"}
  ]
}
```